# Using Turkish letters in RStudio

Tags: character-encoding, letter, turkish

When I save an R script containing Turkish letters such as ş,İ,ı in RStudio with ISO-8859-1, and then open up the same R script again the Turkish letters turn into s,I,i. How can I avoid this situation?

```
> print("ş,İ,ı")
[1] "ş,İ,ı"
```

```
> print("s,I,i")
[1] "s,I,i"
```

```
> Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")
[1] "C"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. At least, show that *strange letters/symbols* corresponding to `ş,ç,ö,ü,İ,ğ,Ç,Ş,Ö,Ü,ı`. Moreover, share `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")`